Dynamically passing data between parents and child windows [MVVM Community Toolkit]
1st parent view model:
[RelayCommand]
public void Popup1Click()
{
    ChildVM childVM = new childVM(this);

    Child child = new Child();
    child.DataContext = childVM;
    child.ShowDialog();
}

2nd parent view model:
[RelayCommand]
public void Popup2Click()
{
    ChildVM childVM = new childVM(this);

    Child child = new Child();
    child.DataContext = childVM;
    child.ShowDialog();
}

Child view model [popup window]:
[ObservableProperty]
private Parent1VM _parentVM;

public NumberPadVM(Parent1VM parentVM)
{
    _parentVM = parentVM;
}

[ObservableProperty]
private string _number = "100";

[RelayCommand]
public void Add(object obj)
{
    Parent1VM.NumberP1 = Number;
}

Problem: from the code above, child can only manipulate Parent 1, but can't manipulate Parent 2.
I wish to make the child window sharable for any parent window called.
For example:
[ObservableProperty]
private Parent1VM _parentVM; // Parent1VM becomes sharable variable type

public NumberPadVM(Parent1VM parentVM) // Parent1VM becomes sharable variable type
{
    _parentVM = parentVM;
}

[ObservableProperty]
private string _number = "100";

[RelayCommand]
public void Add(object obj)
{
    ParentVM.NumberP1 = Number;
    // Besides, I also wish that the control or bound value (NumberP1) can be update dynamically also.
}

